# Residency rules for opening a business bank account in the US

Tags: banking, residency, non-residents

If I open an LLC in the US, can I open a US based business bank account for that LLC in the state where it is incorporated?  I am a US citizen, but a permanent foreign resident.

Do I have to be a resident of the state I open the bank account in, or is it enough to open the account the next time I am in the US visiting family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can but you will need to check with the bank where you will be opening an account on what they require to make this happen.

Bank of America you will need to present 2 forms of Photo ID (Driver's License and Passport) along with corporate information.  One of the IDs needs to be US issued or they can be both foreign issued with a [US Stamped Visa](http://www.yale.edu/oiss/immigration/visa/) in your passport.

So with your US passport you should be able to open an account in the state of incorporation with no issues.

Comment: Do you know what the rules are for Capital One or where I could find that information?

Comment: http://www.capitalone.com/small-business-bank/what-you-need-to-open-account/?Log=1&EventType=Link&ComponentType=T&LOB=MTS%3A%3ALVFX4215&PageName=Checking+Accounts+Overview&PortletLocation=4%3B4-12-col%3B2-6-1-1&ComponentName=Ready+to+open+an+account+spark+business+checking%3B14&ContentElement=1%3BSEE+WHAT+YOU+NEED+TO+BRING&TargetLob=MTS%3A%3ALVFX4215&TargetPageName=Checking+Account+What+You+Need+to+Open&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.capitalone.com%2Fsmall-business-bank%2Fchecking-accounts